# Como interromper um ciclo de "whiles"?

Tags: while, kotlin, break

Bom, vou dar um exemplo muito abstrato de forma a conseguir expressar a minha dúvida de maneira mais simples

Eu tenho seguinte codigo:

```
while(a>b){ // Meu while principal

while(c>d){

while(e>f){

}
}
}
```

Existe algum comando, de forma a que eu deia dentro de um dos meus `whiles`, e ele volte para o `while` principal? Se sim, qual seria o comando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código não é muito claro do que quer, mas seria mais ou menos isto:

```
loop@ while (a > b){ // Meu while principal
    while (c > d) {
        while (e > f) {
            break@loop
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/BreakLabel.kt).